# msxml6.dll error '800c0005' The system cannot locate the resource specified

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, httprequest, msxml

**EDIT 1:** According to my domain provider, the problem is not coming from our server. they tried accessing the URL in the request from a browser physically on the server my website is on and they say it works. i would guess that accessing through a the browser goes a different "route" and maybe wasn't blocked? Also, they say they disabled the firewall on the server and the result was the same.

In the effort of connecting to the WhatsApp API through 360diualog I was successfully sending http requests using the code below:

```
Set SXHttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    SXHttp.Open "GET", "https://waba.360dialog.io/v1/configs/phone_number"
    SXHttp.SetRequestHeader "D360-API-KEY", "API_KEY_HERE"
    SXHttp.Send
```

Sadly, a few days ago this code started returning this error on line `SXHttp.Send`:

```
msxml6.dll error '800c0005'
The system cannot locate the resource specified.
/wa/setwebhook.asp, line 10
```

in the effort of debugging I added there:

```
response.write("Err.Number: "&Err.Number&"<BR>")
response.write("Err.Description: "&Err.Description&"<BR>")
response.write("Err.Source: "&Err.Source&"<BR>")
response.write("status: "&SXHttp.status&"<BR>")
response.write("statusText: "&SXHttp.statusText&"<BR>")
response.write("readyState: "&SXHttp.readyState&"<BR>")
response.write("responseBody: "&SXHttp.responseBody&"<BR>")
response.write("responseStream: "&SXHttp.responseStream&"<BR>")
```

and that returned:

```
Err.Number: -2146697211
Err.Description: The system cannot locate the resource specified.
Err.Source: msxml6.dll
status: 12029
statusText:
readyState: 4
responseBody:
responseStream:
```

**Since**, I am using successfully the same code directed to 2 different services (1. sending regular text messages; 2. creating invoices). **And**, when sending a request from postman.com it works. **I think** this means the problem has to do with the specific pairing of my server and the 360dialog server?

also, I've think that status `12029` means:

```
ERROR_INTERNET_CANNOT_CONNECT inetmsg.h
ERROR_INTERNET_CANNOT_CONNECT wininet.h
```

Err.Number: `-2146697211` is some signed in 32bit thingmajig that I tried converting with 5 different calculators all all gave me a different answer, so I guess I'm not doing it right.

conclusion:

1. the request to 360Dialog gives error
2. same request method works when sent to sms or invoice servers
3. postman request to 360Dialog with the same request doesn't return errors

QUESTION:
how should I proceed? what might be the cause?

Comment: It means something is blocking access to the address (firewall maybe). Have you tried postman on the server in question?

Comment: For errors - negative numbers in COM or NTStatus are signed 32 integers. If the number is positive it is a signed 64 bit number. If 32 bit it may be padded out to 64 bit with `FFFFFFFF` prefix.

Comment: contacted my hosting support, will get back with their reply.

Comment: Acording to my provider, they don't have any firewall rule against the server i am trying to reach. any clue where i need to tell them to look?

Comment: also, we are still able to receive requests on our webhook page from https://waba.360dialog.io. is it possible that it is only blocked in one direction?

Comment: 12029 translate to HTTP 429  - The HTTP 429 Too Many Requests response status code indicates the user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting"). - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429 .

Comment: @bad_coder I don't know why you closed to something irrelevant.

Comment: @Lundt 12029 is the status of the XMLHTTP object. the status of the page running this request is 500.

Comment: https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml